# Number of a serial port in serproxy

Tags: serial, com-port

I have connected my Uno32 chip kit which contains PIC microcontroller to a PC over COM2. Now I have to serial communicate the data which is passed by that controller.

I use `serproxy` to which I have to give a number of the port to which I connected my controller. That number is like `5331` or `5332` etc. How can I find the number of the port to which I connected my controller?

Comment: It is always better to at least quickly look into a documentation first. Did the reply help you?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of [`serproxy`](http://www.lspace.nildram.co.uk/freeware.html) you will find that you have to specify the identification of the serial port - for example `comm_ports=1,3` while the number `5331` you wrote corresponds to the [TCP port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_%28computer_networking%29) `serproxy` will listen on. See the parameter `net_port1=5331`.